# Order of Component Templates in XPM

Tags: 2013-sp1, experience-manager

Does anyone know what is the criteria of the order in which the Component Templates are displayed in the ribbon toolbar in Experience Manager? Is it possible to establish what is the default Component Template when you want to insert a new Component (despite the use of regions)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IIRC, you can specify which CTs are allowed as part of the region configuration/markup. Not sure about the order

Answer (score 1):

In Component Template definition inside Content Manager, you can define **Priority** to control it's order. FYI, For each Page template, you can restrict Component templates to be used.

Comment: I don't think this priority is used in XPM, this is for linking priority.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware there is no way to specify the order in which the Component Templates are listed in the Layout tab of the Ribbon Bar in XPM.

I'm not a 100% sure what is determining the order, it is either one of the following I believe:

1. The order is simply by item ID, the item with the lowest ID is displayed first
2. The order is based on the order of the Templates in the `allowedComponentTypes` of the `Start Region` XPM markup

I'm pretty sure it is following #1, but #2 might be in play, and is something you could try in case you have a `Start Region` XPM markup on your Page.

Comment: Thanks Bart. I'll try with the Regions allowedComponentTypes.

Comment: Based on the comments in @Peter's [answer on SO on regions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14157469/395495), I'd _assume_ the order for the list of Component Template icons in XPM is also by `GetListComponentTemplates` (#1 in @Bart's answer), which is controllable by a Data Extender. Maybe someone closer to the code could confirm. :-)